# gapi.client.youtube is undefined when accessing YouTube API from Angular app

Tags: angular, youtube-api

I have had this issue for a long time. Similar questions that have been asked but there are no proper answers or there is a different problem in user code. My code works no problem for other components like Gmail and Calendar, but for some reason failing for YouTube... Here are the steps:

> I have installed gapi libraries for my app:

```
"@types/gapi": "0.0.39",
"@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.53",
"@types/gapi.client.calendar": "^3.0.10",
"@types/gapi.client.gmail": "^1.0.3",
"@types/gapi.client.youtube": "^3.0.2",
```

> Added references to these libs in tsconfig.app.json for intellisense and type checking:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "gapi.auth2", 
      "gapi.client", 
      "gapi.client.gmail", 
      "gapi.client.calendar",
      "gapi.client.youtube"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

In the app I am using Google OAuth to sign in and on **ngOnInit** of each component I subscribed to sign in status monitoring. When sign in status changes we can call Google API.

> Below is a code fragment for CalendarComponent:

```
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  events: any[];
  constructor(private service: AppService, private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.isSignedIn.subscribe(isSignedIn => this.zone.run(() => { 
      isSignedIn ? this.getEvents(10) : this.events = null; this.createCalendar();
    }));
  }

  getEvents(count: number) {
    this.service.getEvents().then(data => this.zone.run(() => {
      this.events = data;
    }));
  }

}
```

> and code fragment for YoutubeComponent:

```
export class YoutubeComponent implements OnInit {
  items: any[];

  constructor(private service: AppService, private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.isSignedIn.subscribe(isSignedIn => this.zone.run(() => { 
      isSignedIn ? this.getSubscriptions() : this.items = null;
    }));
  }

  getSubscriptions() {
    this.service.getSubscriptions().then(data => this.zone.run(() => {
      this.items = data;
    }));
  }

}
```

As you can see these code fragment are basically identical, the same logic - we call the corresponding method from AppService, where the actual Google API is called.

> Authentication and Sign in status change subscription works perfectly.

In each component there is **ngOnInit** event handler which has a subscription to monitor Google sign in status. When the sign in status changes to **true**, that means a user is signed in, the API is being called. So, from the components we call corresponding AppService methods:

> getEvents() for Calendar:

```
getEvents() {
  return gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list().then(response => {
  // For simplicity’s sake I didnt paste the entire code here...
}
```

> and getSubscriptions() for YouTube correspondingly:

```
getSubscriptions() {
  return gapi.client.youtube.subscriptions.list().then(response => {
    // For simplicity’s sake I didnt paste the entire code here...
  });
}
```

**Question:** Although the logic and code for calling the APIs are essentially identical and respond correctly to sign in status change, for some reason, in the **getSubscriptions()** method of AppService, **gapi.client.youtube** is undefined !! while in **getEvents()** method **gapi.client.calendar** is defined just fine and works correctly. **Any idea why this is happening?**

Here is the debugger screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do you have something like `gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() { ... });` in your code? (`gapi.client.load` is asynchronous.)

Comment: No, I am using Google gapi library, as on the screen